# ASP.NET MVC VaryByParm with OutputCache not working with no query string parameter in actionresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

Why would `/39/adidas-super-64?r=9` not clear the cache when `r` changes?  Does it have to be in the action result method as a parameter?

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "eventid,r")]
public virtual ActionResult Headlines(int eventId, string eventName, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate parameters by a semicolon, not comma.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybyparam%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> A semicolon-separated list of strings that correspond to query-string values for the GET method, or to parameter values for the POST method.

Also, changing a parameter doesn't **clear** the cache but creates a different cached version.